# In Notepad++ how do I find the nth "\" in a line?

Tags: notepad++

I am migrating from Musicbee back to iTunes (for library management reasons) but unfortunately that means I'm having to deal with filename truncating again (iTunes limits filename size, including track number and extension, to 40 characters). I do not sync my entire library to my devices, only a few playlists, which unfortunately became compromised during the migration. So now I am using Notepad++ to copy over the raw text from the old .MBP files to a new .M3U textfile. I managed to get each file location on it's own line, but now I'm trying to truncate the filenames on each line and there are 3000+ lines.

Ideally what I need specifically is to find the 7th occurrence of "\" in each line (this would find the end of the album folder string), and then to tell it go 36 characters (need to leave 4 columns for the ".mp3" at the end of each line) and then delete everything after the 36th character, including any trailing spaces, and then add the ".mp3" back to the end.

Example:

```
C:\Users\USER\Music\iTunes\ARTIST\ALBUM\01 A Really Really Really Really Long Track Name.mp3
```

Becomes:

```
C:\Users\USER\Music\iTunes\ARTIST\ALBUM\01 A Really Really Really Really Lo.mp3
```

Fair warning, I am very new to Notepad++. I have only really used a bit of TextFX but I'm aware that's it's capable of advanced Find/Replace expressions. I tried looking up similar requests on SO, but couldn't quite get anything I could understand or adapt.

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong place for this. Try SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to have "get all including up to first 36 characters after last backslash":

Search Regex

```
(.*\\.{1,36})[^\\]*.mp3
```

Replace with

```
\1.mp3
```

Gets you:
C:\Users\USER\Music\iTunes\ARTIST\ALBUM\01 A Really Really Really Really Lon.mp3

(1 char more than your result, still 40 in my counting, if wrong, replace 36 with 35).